# How to create an image dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create an images dataset as .mat file for automatic detection using multiclass svm algorithm in MATLAB. We are unable to a .mat file of images dataset for training and classification purpose of an image. My question is how to create an image dataset and how to save and load that dataset for testing in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

Since images are nothing else than normal matrices in Matlab I would recommend you using the command save and load. It can be used to save all variables into a .mat file. To save the image with its labels (if the images have constant size) i would reshape the image into a 1Xn array and concatenate the image with its metadata and labels like that:

|data|metadata(a.e. height,width)|labels.

Afterwards I would stack the data to a m+1xn array with a short explanation of the data in the first row. With m the number of images you have. Afterwards save it with the save command. If you want to reuse the data you can bring it to the original shape using width and height.

You can find the documentation here:
Save:
https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html
Load:
https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html

PS: for more compatibility you could consider writing into csv files instead of a .mat file therefore you can use csvwrite: https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html

Comment: What if the images are sequence of frames of videos with their labels ? I want to create a data set of 1400 videos of different length (some are 7 mints and some are 2 or 3 mints)with at least 11 labels to each video ? Any help